# NumPy array from .txt file too large to load into memory

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large .txt file of around 6Gb with the following structure:

```
0.1 0.4 0.9 1.2 0.2 3.8
2.8 4.2 0.3 1.9
0.3 5.8 9.6 0.05 2.2
```

which I turn into a NumPy array with `.loadtxt(file.txt)` to get:

```
[[0.1 0.4 0.9 1.2 0.2 3.8], [2.8 4.2 0.3 1.9], [0.3 5.8 9.6 0.05 2.2]]
```

The file is now too large to load into memory and I get a memory error, so I`ve been trying to load it in chunks with this

```
def loadFile(filePath):
chunk_size = 10000
data = []
with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = np.genfromtxt(f, max_rows=chunk_size)
        if len(chunk) < chunk_size:
            # Last chunk 
            data.append(chunk)
            break 
        data.append(chunk)
        # Move pointer to start of next chunk
        f.seek(chunk_size-len(chunk), 1)

# Joining chunks into a single array
data = np.concatenate(data)
return data
```

With the thought that I`d only need to load a single chunk into memory at a time, but this still ends up maxing my RAM and crashing my PC.

What am I missing? Splitting the file up into multiple files really isn`t an option.

Comment: The rows have different numbers of columns, 6,4,5 in the sample.  Doesn't `gen` complain about that?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `chunking` to break up a large data file you are supposed to `load` that chunk of data into memory, `process` it and then `free` up the memory. What you are doing in your code is `chunking` the data, adding it to the `data` array and then `concatenating` the chunks into a single array. Which is the **equivalent** **of** **loading the entire data file at once** except with extra steps. If you require the entire data set to do your processing, you might need to upgrade your hardware or look for alternative modules. However, if you don't need to use the entire dataset you can do your processing in the `while` loop that is reading the chunks:

```
with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = np.genfromtxt(f, max_rows=chunk_size)
        if len(chunk) < chunk_size:
            # Last chunk 
            data.append(chunk)
            break 
        #Do some processing here
        [insert code]
        # Move pointer to start of next chunk
        f.seek(chunk_size-len(chunk), 1)
```

Comment: totally makes sense now, thanks. What if I concatenate the chunks on to the main array one at a time in the loop instead of all at once at the end?

Comment: That would lead to the same issue because your computer does not have enough memory to load a 6Gb file into memory.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you could try to specify a smaller data type. It alone probably won't solve the issue, but should help.

Python's `float` values are usually 64-bit, close to C's `double`. In Numpy, you could use `numpy.single` (32-bit) or `numpy.half` (16-bit).
To specify the data type, you must pass a `dtype` as an argument to `loadtxt`. For example:

```
data = np.loadtxt(fileName, dtype=np.half)
```

#### References (from Numpy's docs):

- `loadtxt`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html
- NumPy's Data types: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html